# Are there any nonlocal one-body operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, non-locality

In case I have a one-body operator given by
$$
\hat{O}=\int d^3r\int d^3r' \,\hat\psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\langle \mathbf{r}|\hat O|\mathbf{r}'\rangle\hat\psi(\mathbf{r}'),
$$
are there any operators where I cannot simplify $\langle \mathbf{r}|\hat O|\mathbf{r}'\rangle$ to $O(\mathbf{r})\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$ and obtain
$$
\hat{O}=\int d^3r\,\hat\psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r})O(\mathbf{r})\hat\psi(\mathbf{r})?
$$

Comment: What you are describing is not a non-local operator, but a non-diagonal operator in position. So for example single particle momentum could not be simplified in this way

Comment: @BySymmetry I'm not sure you are correct. The partial derivative in position space is considered local. Specifically, you would get $\hat{P} = -i\hbar \int d^3r \psi^{\dagger}({\bf r})\nabla \psi({\bf r})$ (you can get it as a local derivative of a delta function, and then use integration by parts to move the derivative onto the field)

Comment: @yu-v If $\hat P$ is local, and the class of local operators is closed under addition and multiplication, then the displacement operator $\exp(i\hat P a)$ is also local, regardless of how large $a$ is, right? (meaning: maybe one can acknowledge that 'local operator' is a soft concept with fuzzy edges, and that a hard stance on whether $\hat P$ is local or not is not really workable either way.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yes the definition is fuzzy. A local operator for me is something that depends only on the value of the field *and its derivatives* at a point $r$. However, of course, once we allow derivatives, it not truly local, as it "knows" about the value of the field at near-by points. But this is the definition I feel comfortable with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [comments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/512080/are-there-any-nonlocal-one-body-operators#comment1154007_512080),

> are there any operators where I cannot simplify $\langle \mathbf{r}|\hat O|\mathbf{r}'\rangle$ to $O(\mathbf{r})\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$ and obtain
>   $$
> \hat{O}=\int d^3r\,\hat\psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r})O(\mathbf{r})\hat\psi(\mathbf{r})?
> $$

Yes, there are ─ the momentum operator is the trivial example, and it cannot be described in this way.

However, the name "local" is not necessarily the best way to describe the property that you're after here, and such an operator is best described as non-diagonal in the position representation.

Ultimately, "local" and "nonlocal" are fuzzy terms and they have a broad gray zone around them where there are operators (like momentum) which may or may not be "local" depending on how much you care about information staying strictly at a single spatial location. By a strict definition, derivatives require information from points next to where you are, so there is a reasonable argument that none of them are "local", but on the other hand, in practice having one or two derivatives is fine and most people will consider momentum to be a local operator.

The problem is that if you go beyond allowing single derivatives into allowing multiple derivatives, then you start allowing information from more and more points far away from the point of interest, and at some point things get unreasonable. Moreover, there isn't a clear line where things get unreasonable, so the placement of that line (including whether it includes single derivatives or not) is a subjective matter.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is nothing that prevents you from writing such a term. The question is whether such non-local one particle operator will occur in a physical system. On the face of it, this operator 'teleports' a particle from ${\bf r}$ to ${\bf r}'$ instantly. Therefore, normally we would suspect any such single particle operator as unphysical.

However, in effective theories such non-local operators may occur. For example, in 1d topological system with Majorana quasiparticles at the end, there can exist a non-local term that couples them and allows you to 'teleport' between them (see [this](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.104.056402) famous paper by Fu). However, this is of course some effective theory which the result of integrating-out a lot of local operators.